# "As of " + future?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct?

> As of next year, I will be studying [insert a field of study].

I know that "From next year on, ..." and "Starting next year, ..." are better options, but just want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the meaning of the phrase “as of” takes different forms.

Ambiguity is caused because “as of” has three different meanings: **on, since or from**

e.g.:

- The contract enters into force as of 1 January 2013. = on
- The contract has been effective as of 1 August 2011. = since
- The contract is effective as of 1 January 2013. = from

However, I have heard often the following usage:
The contract was terminated *as of* 1 January 2012.

Refrence: Mind the Gaffe: The Penguin Guide to Common Errors in English- suggests to best avoid it in most writing; and *rather use on, since, or from instead.*

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, at least [according to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of).

From a personal perspective, I would definitely say that it is an awkward construction.  I see the "as of + *future*" construction more commonly used in phrases with definite dates like:

> The law starts as of January 10th next year.
>
> School is out as of July 1st, 2015.
>
> I will be your manager as of the 10th of next month.