# How do I distinguish between several meanings of "as of"?

Tags: phrases, differences, phrase-meaning

In a few answers here, people quote Cambridge dictionary and state that "as of" means "starting from a particular time".

> **starting from a particular time or date:**
>    **As of** next month, all the
>   airline's fares will be going up.

However, if you look up "as" in the same dictionary, you can find "as of" explained (also) as follows:

> **at a particular date or time**:
>   *1) The data is correct **as of** May 13.*   // so it is like a snapshot of data taken on May 13.
>
> 2) This issue may need attention later but, **as of** now, we are happy with the
>   decision that we have taken.*

In addition, other dictionaries clearly state that it can also mean "up until a point in time", for example:

> **As of** now, only two bodies have been discovered.

As shown above, it can also indicate "on a particular date (only), and this is confirmed in the Longman dictionary:
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as-of

> **on a particular date**SYNas at BrE
>   *As of August 1, the company had $44
>   million in long-term debt.*

So, how do I tell? And why so many people tend to know only the "basic" meaning (starting from a particular time)?
E.g. in this dictionary, the meanings are not clear to me:https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of

Comment: I don't see where you are showing evidence for saying '[why] so many people tend to know only the "basic" meaning' (whichever you think that one is), and even if it is true, it is a question for educationalists rather than linguists. Dictionaries are _not_ comprehensive, though I'll wager that OED gives all three of these senses (starting from a particular time or date // at/on a particular time or date // up until a particular time or date) are given in OED. //// Context will almost always disambiguate.

Comment: A simple search here will show you answers in which people confidently say that "as of" means "from a point in time onwards", and that other meanings are not correct.

Comment: It's your job to provide these, not other users'. I've actually looked, and only found one or two relevant answers, saying "A means B". I've not found one saying "A means B, not C." // I **do** agree that the M-W entry could be improved. But ELU doesn't take responsibility for what others print.

Comment: In fact, @Ishan Yadav's answer at [As of – future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202847/as-of-future) mentions the three usages of 'as of' you do. As a simple search shows. // A punctive construction / tense (is correct / are happy / had) will force the 'at a particular date or time' reading

Comment: In fact, @Ishan Yadav's answer at [As of – future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202847/as-of-future) mentions the three usages of 'as of' you do. As a simple search shows. // A punctive construction / tense (is correct / are happy / had) will force the 'at a particular date or time' reading. Contrast 'As of [on] August 1, the company had $44 million in long-term debt.' with 'As of [since] August 1, the company has had $44 million in long-term debt.' and  'As of [from] September 1, the company will have $44 million in long-term debt.'

Comment: ... The 'as of today' etc usage is probably rarer, meaning 'Up until this day / point in time'; it's probably used mainly with negatives such as 'As of today, we've had no success in finding any more bodies.' I think it probably uses a perfect construction (have had; has been had ...)  most or all of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["As of " + future?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202847/as-of-future)

Answer (score -1):

"As of" right now im going to answer your question.  When you read this hopefully you can say "As of right now I understand the use"..."As of" is always used in the same manner it never really changes. Its always stating things up to a specific point in time. In all of your examples its used in the same way

Comment: The thing is, as shown in the examples, it can mean "from", "at/on" and even "until". Even some native speakers were not able to tell me the differences.

Comment: Most commonly, "as of" is used to express "from a point in time onwards" (that is the basic meaning in Cambridge): As of next week, the prices will go up by 25%.